# Prägnante Übersetzung von engl. "views" (wie in "42 views of this post")

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich suche nach einem kurzen und prägnanten Begriff für "view", wie er in Internet-Foren und auch hier auf StackExchange verwendet wird.

> This post has 42 views.

*"Ansichten"* erscheint mir etwas holprig und *"gesehen/gelesen von"* etwas zu lang.

Comment: Viel schwieriger finde ich die Übersetzung des Wortes "post". Beitrag, Nachricht, Eintrag, Seite? Die Post finde ich im Briefkasten :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Aufrufe** ist zwar noch etwas lang, aber es ist zumindest treffend.

Comment: Aufrufe seems to be even better adapted than 'views' in the Internet context.

Answer (score 5):

**Views** scheint sich als Anglizismus durchzusetzen, ähnlich wie die *Likes* bei Facebook.

Unter Webmastern ist es schon seit Jahren üblich, die Aufrufe von Webseiten als *Views* zu bezeichnen:

> Die Seite XY hat 25.000 **Views** pro Tag. Nachdem der Link umbenannt wurde, stieg die Zahl der **Views** um 10 %.

Comment: Ich bin der Meinung, man sollte unnötige Anglizismen vermeiden, wenn es einen deutschen *Begriff* (nicht unbedingt Wort) schon gibt.

Comment: @Yves: Ich stimme dir vollkommen zu. Aber welchen deutschen Begriff gibt es, der genau dasselbe wie das englische Wort "View" bedeutet? Mir fällt keiner ein. Und wie man hier nachlesen kann, scheint es auch keinen Konsens über so einen Begriff zu geben. Daher fürchte ich, dass der Anglizismus "View", der als Fachbegriff ohnehin schon längst etabliert ist, leider nötig ist.

Comment: Als Englischer Fachbegriff scheint "view" auch nicht optimal zu sein. Viele Page-Views Zähler zählen in der Tat nur die (HTTP) Anfragen der Webseite, welche eigentlich nicht viel über das sagen, was gelesen wurde. Der Begriff scheint mir zB besser zu "Aufrufe" zu passen (von YouTube oder von dir verwendet). Als Fachbegriff in der Web-Analyse und SMO/SEO wird ausserdem auch "Page Impression" (auf Englisch, auf Deutsch scheinbar nur auf Wikipedia) benutzt (Beim W3C findet man interessante Diskussionen über das Versuch einer neuen Definition).

Comment: Aber letzendlich ist sowieso nur das gültig, was sich in dem Sprachgebrauch durchsetzt.

Answer (score 4):

Es ist tatsächlich schwer, den Beispielsatz ähnlich kurz und prägnant zu übersetzen. Es gibt kein auch nur annähernd passendes Nomen für *["views"](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=View&l=deen&in=&lf=en)*. Nachdem die wörtliche Übersetzung *"Dieser Posten hat 42 Besichtigungen"* wie eine schlecht übersetzte Bedienungsanleitung klingt, wäre meine Vorschlag, die Aussage mit Hilfe eines Verbs wie folgt zu übersetzen:

> Diese Nachricht wurde 42 mal gelesen<sup>*</sup>.
>   <sup>**Alternativen:** angesehen, aufgerufen, betrachtet, gesehen, ...</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Was in Blogs und Foren angezeigt wird, ist nicht das Verhalten der Webseitenbesucher, sondern Seitenaufrufe durch und Zustände im Browser.

Es ist technisch völlig unmöglich festzustellen, ob und was jemand gelesen hat, der eine Seite aufruft. Selbst wenn eine Seite fünf Minuten im Browser ist, ist der Seitenbesucher währenddessen möglicherweise nur auf dem Klo und klickt sie dann ungelesen weg. Auch wenn der Browser Bilder, die in eine HTML-Seite eingebunden sind, vom Server abruft, kann es sein, dass der Browser ihre Darstellung unterdrückt, so dass sie trotz "view" für den Mensch vor dem Computer unsichtbar sind.

Im technischen Jargon ("Webmaster-Slang") gebräuchlich sind überwiegend die englischen Begriffe selbst. Für Endnutzer (z.B. von Google Analytics oder Wordpress) werden die Begriffe häufig folgendermaßen übersetzt:

> **(page)views** *Aufrufe* (Abruf einer bestimmten Seite oder eines
>   bestimmten Inhalts)
>
> **visits** *Besuche* (Aufruf irgendeiner Seite unterhalb der Domain)